# Why does Intel Power Gadget fully freeze the system?

Tags: cpu, power-management, macos

I have installed Intel Power Gadget. When I've tried to start the app it fully freezes system. I then need to reboot.

I have the problem with a MacBook Air (i7, 2012) with a clean install of macOS 10.11.6. On an iMac (i5, 2014) also U CPU model, and same macOS 10.11.6, starting the app works and it shows what I need.

Why does Intel Power Gadget not work on the MacBook Air.

Comment: Why install power gadget ? When you install , where is it installed - does it write over system files?

Comment: i use power gadget to saw my cpu graph, when installing just click to *.pkg file and use system disk where to install

Comment: What is wrong with the app provided by Apple in the utilities folder called Activity Monitor? That does not crash the system - I use it often, also you can control processes etc...

Comment: @Solar There are certain things Intel Power Gadget shows which Activity Monitor doesn't, so there are legitimate reasons to install it.

Comment: If it crashes the system then it is not showing anything...

Comment: Activity monitor is lying it's not showing correct real cpu loading, also intel power gadget that installed on imac shows watts and AI loading

Comment: What shutdown code are you getting?

Comment: Only grey screen of death!

Answer (score 1):

I would uninstall Power Gadget fully then reinstall from a fresh download of 3.5.2.

I have it running successfully on an 2012 13" MBP i7 w/ 10.11 w/ no problems, as well as a 2015 15" MBP i7 w/ 10.13

Is everything else ok, e.g. Apple Diagnostics/Apple Hardware Test, SMC, etc.?